# WinSCP .NET assembly: Set a custom event handler to Session.FileTransferred in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli, winscp, winscp-net, eventhandler

Sorry I have a bit specified question. Yes this is related to setting a custom Event Handler to an event. Yes, this type of questions may have already been asked many times, but here I have to restrict to WinSCP situation.

Refer to example in `Session.SynchronizeDirectories` method:
http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_synchronizedirectories

I am converting the C# example to C++/CLI, but encounter a problem.

In C#, it is a no-brainer to set as:

```
Session session = new Session();
session.FileTransferred += FileTransferred;
...
private static void FileTransferred(object sender, TransferEventArgs e)
{
    ....
}
```

In C++/CLI, I do the following:

```
WinSCP::Session ^ session = gcnew WinSCP::Session();
session->FileTransferred += gcnew EventHandler(FileTransferred);
...

static void FileTransferred(System::Object ^sender, WinSCP::TransferEventsArgs ^e)
{
    ....
}
```

But I get this error:

> function FileTransferred() does not match the delegate type 'void (System::Object ^, System::EventArgs ^)'.

I try changing to `FileTransferred(System::Object ^sender, EventArgs ^e)`, but then the whole body of `FileTransferred()` become invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  session->FileTransferred += gcnew EventHandler(FileTransferred);
```

EventHandler is the wrong delegate type.  You need to create a WinSCP FileTransferredEventHandler delegate instead.  Fix:

```
  session->FileTransferred += gcnew WinSCP::FileTransferredEventHandler(FileTransferred);
```

Beware that you also mis-spelled WinSCP::TransferEventsArgs, one s too many.

Answer (score 0):

I actually was just a step away from the answer.

In C#, after typing the `+=` after `session.FileTransferred`, I was prompted to hit Tab button. I then saw the following:

```
session.FileTransferred += new FileTransferredEventHandler(FileTransferred);
```

This `FileTransferredEventHandler()` could pick up the correct function signature `FileTransferred(object sender, TransferEventArgs e)` (instead of requiring `FileTransferred(object sender, EventArgs e)`.

I go back to C++/CLI and do the same:

```
session->FileTransferred += gcnew FileTransferredEventHandler(FileTransferred);
```

Compile. And no complain.